# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker.for.linux.localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/user

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, postman

In ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I am getting this error

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker.for.linux.localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/user

Actually I have made two docker images for flask and django.
In flask app,

my main.py:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root:root@db/main'
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)



@dataclass
class Product(db.Model):
    id: int
    title: str
    image: str

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    image = db.Column(db.String(200))

@dataclass
class ProductUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'product_id', name='user_product_unique')

@app.route('/api/products')
def index():
    return jsonify(Product.query.all())

@app.route('/api/products/<int:id>/like', methods=['POST'])
def like(id):
    req = requests.get('http://docker.for.linux.localhost:8000/api/user')
    return jsonify(req.json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python main.py'
    ports:
      - 8001:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python3 -u consumer.py'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33067:3306
```

when I am entering the url in *postman*
**http://localhost:8001/api/products/1/like**
by post method
I am getting the above error mentioned in the question

Can anyone tell how to fix this solution?

Comment: did you find any answer ?   `172.17.0.1`  or  `docker.for.lin.localhost` nothing works on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 for me `http://docker.for.win.localhost:8000/api/user` worked. you can try using `lin` or check and confirm the Linux abbreviation for this.

```
req = requests.get('http://docker.for.win.localhost:8000/api/user')
json = req.json()
```

Comment: try req =requests.get('http://docker.for.lin.localhost:8000/api/user')

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and for me `http://172.17.0.1:8000/api/user` worked.
To get `172.17.0.1`, I ran `ifconfig` in Terminal and looked for `docker0`.